# Error in Table based Jasperreport deployed at Tomcat server

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a table based jasperreport which works fine on Jasperstudio Preview but shows error when I compile and deploy it on Tomcat. Reports other than Table compenent works fine on tomcat.
Error for table based report:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport.createCell(TableReport.java:1629)
    net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport$ReportBandCreator.createColumnCell(TableReport.java:521)
    net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport$ColumnHeaderCreator.createColumnCell(TableReport.java:733)
    net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport$ColumnHeaderCreator.createColumnCell(TableReport.java:710)
    net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport$ReportBandCreator.visitColumn(TableReport.java:500)
    net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport$ReportBandCreator.visitColumn(TableReport.java:466)
    net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.StandardColumn.visitColumn(StandardColumn.java:74)
    net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport$ReportBandCreator.visit(TableReport.java:579)
    net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport.createColumnHeader(TableReport.java:1141)
    net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.TableReport.<init>(TableReport.java:324)
    net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable.createFillTableSubreportFactory(FillTable.java:335)
    net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable.createFillSubreport(FillTable.java:309)
    net.sf.jasperreports.components.table.fill.FillTable.evaluate(FillTable.java:131)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillComponentElement.evaluate(JRFillComponentElement.java:110)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:381)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:500)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummaryNoLastFooterSamePage(JRVerticalFiller.java:1064)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillSummary(JRVerticalFiller.java:1025)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:161)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:582)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.fill(BaseReportFiller.java:396)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:90)
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:286)
    de.oc.integration.jasper.webapp.ReportWrapper.service(Unknown Source)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

My Jasperreport Source

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.12.2.final using JasperReports Library version 6.12.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Iteminwardslandscape" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8a465670-cc4a-4270-965f-8efb86e33b71">
    <property name="template.engine" value="tabular_template"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="test connection"/>
    <style name="Table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#EFEFEF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="tableDataset" uuid="5bda4d95-20f7-4d38-bc52-cdecce81ae1b">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="test connection"/>
        <parameter name="STOCK_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[select * from t_stock_detail sd join
t_stock_master sm on sd.stock_id = sm.stock_id
join t_unit_measure uom on sd.uom_id = uom.id
join t_items  i on sd.item_id = i.item_id
join t_item_condition ic on sd.item_condition_id = ic.item_condition_id
join t_ledger l on l.ledger_id = i.ledger_id 
WHERE sm.stock_id =  $P{STOCK_ID}]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="ID"/>
        </field>
        <field name="STOCK_ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="STOCK_ID"/>
        </field>
        <field name="ITEM_ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="ITEM_ID"/>
        </field>
        <field name="ORIGINAL" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="ORIGINAL"/>
        </field>
        <field name="ACTUAL" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="ACTUAL"/>
        </field>
        <field name="WIDTH" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="WIDTH"/>
        </field>
        <field name="LENGTH" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="LENGTH"/>
        </field>
        <field name="STOCKQTY" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="STOCKQTY"/>
        </field>
        <field name="KANTA" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="KANTA"/>
        </field>
        <field name="RATE" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="RATE"/>
        </field>
        <field name="PACKET" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="PACKET"/>
        </field>
        <field name="LABEL_METER" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="LABEL_METER"/>
        </field>
        <field name="NAME" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="NAME"/>
        </field>
        <field name="LEDGER_ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="LEDGER_ID"/>
        </field>
        <field name="COLUMN_31" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="ITEM_CONDITION_ID"/>
        </field>
        <field name="CONDITION" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="CONDITION"/>
        </field>
        <field name="COLUMN_33" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="ACTIVE"/>
        </field>
        <field name="COLUMN_34" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="LEDGER_ID"/>
        </field>
        <field name="ACCOUNT_CODE" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="ACCOUNT_CODE"/>
        </field>
        <field name="ACCOUNT_NATURE" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="ACCOUNT_NATURE"/>
        </field>
        <field name="ADDRESS1" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="ADDRESS1"/>
        </field>
        <field name="ADDRESS2" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="ADDRESS2"/>
        </field>
        <field name="MOBILE" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="MOBILE"/>
        </field>
        <field name="LANDLINE" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="LANDLINE"/>
        </field>
        <field name="FAX" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="FAX"/>
        </field>
        <field name="EMAIL" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="EMAIL"/>
        </field>
        <field name="NTN_NO" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="NTN_NO"/>
        </field>
        <field name="SALES_TAX_NO" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="SALES_TAX_NO"/>
        </field>
        <field name="CNIC" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="CNIC"/>
        </field>
        <field name="PAYMENT_TERMS" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="PAYMENT_TERMS"/>
        </field>
        <field name="CREATED_ON" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="CREATED_ON"/>
        </field>
        <field name="CREATED_BY" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="CREATED_BY"/>
        </field>
        <field name="UPDATED_ON" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="UPDATED_ON"/>
        </field>
        <field name="UPDATED_BY" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="UPDATED_BY"/>
        </field>
        <field name="COLLECTOR_ID" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="COLLECTOR_ID"/>
        </field>
        <field name="LEDGER_DESCRIPTION" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.field.label" value="LEDGER_DESCRIPTION"/>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="STOCK_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <title>
        <band height="56" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="-20" y="0" width="822" height="56" uuid="1a03a12c-458b-4eca-8787-8a9d54804390"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="26"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Item Inwards Report]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="38" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="200" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="local_mesure_unitheight" value="pixel"/>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="820" height="200" uuid="4d9aaea1-bd91-47d4-aef5-d74e66e37240">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.table_header" value="Table_TH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.column_header" value="Table_CH"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.table.style.detail" value="Table_TD"/>
                </reportElement>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" whenNoDataType="Blank">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="tableDataset" uuid="f1b23deb-5b3f-45b3-acaa-fa56d0c6824e">
                        <datasetParameter name="STOCK_ID">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{STOCK_ID}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="66" uuid="d5acd7c1-830d-410a-b053-a4e90fefb28d">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="c15e662d-17c5-4ffd-933c-e9a30cd6f8d5"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="fe490009-312c-4a2d-a8eb-3d42505e50eb"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="66" uuid="0a780390-af03-4d1a-84c4-9eb94f2e5ba7">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="8306656d-ef07-4d8c-a931-72a0131cf6f7"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[ITEM_ID]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="fdc1a3d1-2364-4e3f-831e-e868ac812a17"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ITEM_ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="66" uuid="8126feca-69cf-458d-bd89-744d00917cfd">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="64407eea-0f3c-4935-9034-aa7434dbaa17"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[NAME]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="c64ce848-434d-4c89-95cc-75467edba62e"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{NAME}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="82" uuid="3ba4ada4-897b-481c-8c56-3418d463cb76">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="82" height="30" uuid="c17e874e-f0a4-4f6e-afb3-638ecdbf702a"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[CONDITION]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="82" height="30" uuid="11a27a61-8a7d-4fb9-949d-09d910f13d7d"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CONDITION}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="70" uuid="06227fe0-3be2-4b38-9a86-80f2cfc20731">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="1113d914-14c1-409f-8314-2d00ea6c088c"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[ORIGINAL]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="2840bfe5-8016-4728-9ac8-b955b9002cfe"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ORIGINAL}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="66" uuid="84c3b038-62cf-4b4c-8bf3-6f497a81fc78">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="8a80be66-64b8-4c01-8265-0f0edc683abc"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[ACTUAL]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="20cb7ba3-845e-464a-a1d6-4c1a783bb299"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ACTUAL}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="66" uuid="07e2f7c9-80ec-4e47-808d-3126856af4f2">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="116b5911-e01e-4e63-a222-a3185d57fcc6"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[WIDTH]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="6734c42e-33b5-4c1f-b846-b1dc97d33694"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{WIDTH}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="66" uuid="5ab03631-2b44-4d8a-afd6-a03198387fa8">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="9d6293fb-bdab-471e-9a68-3956ae3563bd"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[LENGTH]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="bc091e6b-c2f0-40a2-a77c-4ebf2ce1b9dc"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LENGTH}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="66" uuid="c451bb94-ff75-4650-af1b-64aeeb245f70">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="ec0c6421-d2e9-4c6b-a686-c5a45995fa4a"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[KANTA]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="193c889d-bb33-414b-a843-54af34863029"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{KANTA}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="76" uuid="4ee20376-8573-4c62-b211-3d5fe444078d">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="76" height="30" uuid="957fe4de-cad1-4c99-b75a-4429d654d7a8"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[QUANTITY]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="76" height="30" uuid="6edcef3e-e6ba-4445-af51-62ffb268a9dc"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{STOCKQTY}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="66" uuid="c641a72e-f78c-497b-aabd-46ef0ee484f4">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="8f5a5208-1bc1-4953-80f0-b5581599b253"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[METER]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="4930bdd8-24ca-430e-b97d-de0bc4a38a0a"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LABEL_METER}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="66" uuid="44628f40-c2a8-4fc1-9083-5d8826589c3a">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:tableFooter style="Table_TH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:columnHeader style="Table_CH" height="30">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="bb083ce6-4ace-4dc6-af8c-11bc087181f7"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12" isBold="true"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[LEDGER]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:columnHeader>
                        <jr:columnFooter style="Table_CH" height="30"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="dca8c816-3ec8-4cce-880c-538a6b8b6b02"/>
                                <box leftPadding="2"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans" size="12"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{LEDGER_DESCRIPTION}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

I'm using 
tomcat-8.5.56
Java-Runtime-Version: 14.0.1
Jaspersoft® Studio 6.12.2

Comment: What are the contents of the cell?  And how are you setting the datasource on the Table?  You need to do table data sources a little differently based on JasperStudio vs Tomcat environment.

Comment: For datasource of table, I'm selecting Dataset Run as 'tableDataset' in the master report and using the option 'Use same JBDC connection used to fill the master report' . My tableDataset has query configured.

Comment: What's the version of the jasperreports jar in your Tomcat webapp?  You say you have Jaspersoft Studio 6.12.2, but the stracktrace line numbers do not correspond to jasperreports-6.12.2.jar sources.

Comment: JasperReports-Version: 6.4.1

Comment: I also tried compiling it to  6.4.0 and  6.4.3 in jaspersoft studio but it still shows this error. 
There is no option to compile it on 6.4.1

Comment: And the contents of the cell? Are you using a specific Scriptlet or other class which is not on the class path to format? What do you have set for NULL handling, are you sure data is coming back correctly?  If you change the null handling to NO DATA/BLANK PAGE will it still error out?

Comment: I have edited the question with source of jasperreport. If I change 'When no data type' to blank from null, it still shows this error on tomcat. Report is working fine on jaspersoft studio. I can preview it perfectly.

Comment: Compiling with JasperReports 6.12.2 (which is what Studio 6.12.2 uses by default) and running with JasperReports 6.4.1 will not work.  Compiling with JasperReports 6.4.0 should work thought, I don't know why it doesn't for you.

Comment: tried it. it doesn't :(

Comment: Okay I got it. @dada67 thanks :D